# Is there an automatic check for disposing of SPWeb and SPSite in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I'm reviewing some code and I thought it would be useful for Visual Studio to throw a warning anytime an SPWeb or SPSite object is initiated without using "using(SPSite x = ...){}".

Is there a way to configure this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you need to dispose (e.g. var site = new SPSite()), sometimes you should not dispose (e.g. var web = site.RootWeb). So you can't do warnings based on absolutes.

Your best bet is to use SPDisposeCheck.

Answer (score 0):

Using is a keyword that automatically dispose the object if it is no longer used.

So for spweb and spsite object we put in using keyword that's why they are automatically disposer when not used further.